# Youtube iframe on ipad cant be covered

Tags: javascript, ipad, iframe, youtube

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R3k6s/6/)

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/FPCrhT0q5Ns?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
<a class="close"></a>
.close {
    width: 50px; height: 50px;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 600px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2147483638;
    cursor: pointer;
}​
$(".close").bind("click touchend", function() {
    alert("");
});​
```

1. open jsfiddle in ipad (only)
2. play video
3. try to click on white button

result: click wont work

PS Dont tell me about **wmode**. I've tried all possible values before posting the question

Answer (score 0):

Add the parameter of `wmode=transparent` to the `src` url in the iframe

[Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R3k6s/8/)

Comment: no change. I've tried all wmode types before answering the question of course

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more vigilant. I don't even know if this is possible on iPad as it uses different codecs and not Flash.